# heroku H14 error "No web processes running" for Django 1.82

Tags: python, django, heroku, conda, procfile

Hi I'm learning Django through Onemonth Django. 
I am deploying my web app to heroku but I got the error below.

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"
```

I tried to fix this with `heroku ps:scale web=1` but it resulted below.

```
Scaling dynos... failed
 !    No such process type web defined in Procfile.
```

Could someone help how to fix this? I use conda for making a virtual environment but would it be possibility of causing this?

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi --log-file -
```

`git push heroku master`was successfully run. I use OSX Yosemite/Django 1.82.

The project structure looks like below.

```
Procfile
requirements.txt
core
- views.py
- __init__.py
- admin.py
- migrations
- models.py
- tests.py
- urls.py
- manage.py
nomadscoffee
- wsgi.py
- __init__.py
- settings.py
- urls.py
static
- css
- font-awesome
- img
- fonts
- index.html
- js
- less
- LICENSE
- mail
- README.md
templates
- base
  - index.html
```

Log on heroku:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing runtime (python-2.7.10)
-----> Installing dependencies with pip
       Collecting dj-database-url==0.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Downloading dj_database_url-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
       Collecting dj-static==0.0.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading dj-static-0.0.6.tar.gz
       Collecting Django==1.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Downloading Django-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
       Collecting django-toolbelt==0.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
         Downloading django-toolbelt-0.0.1.tar.gz
       Collecting gunicorn==19.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
         Downloading gunicorn-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (110kB)
       Collecting psycopg2==2.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
         Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
       Collecting static3==0.6.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
         Downloading static3-0.6.1.tar.gz
       Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, static3, dj-static, Django, psycopg2, gunicorn, django-toolbelt
         Running setup.py install for static3
         Running setup.py install for dj-static
         Running setup.py install for psycopg2
         Running setup.py install for django-toolbelt
       Successfully installed Django-1.8.2 dj-database-url-0.3.0 dj-static-0.0.6 django-toolbelt-0.0.1 gunicorn-19.3.0 psycopg2-2.6.1 static3-0.6.1
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 7.1.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
-----> Preparing static assets
       Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
       $ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
-----> Discovering process types
 ~     Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring.
 ~     Rename it to Procfile to have it honored.
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing... done, 54.1MB
-----> Launching... done, v4
       https://something.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: if you really have `myapp.wsgi` in your `Procfile` then change it to `nomadscoffee.wsgi`

Comment: Dariusz, thanks for pointing out. No I changed it intentionally to be clear. It's nomadscoffee.wsgi.

Comment: I tried deleting and creating a new heroku app again but I still get the same error.. PLEASE help :(

Comment: Would the error coming from using conda? If so how can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your error log, I see this:

`Mis-cased procfile detected; ignoring`

This makes me think that the project structure you provided is not correct.  Do you really have `Procfile`, as you indicate, in the root?  Heroku thinks you have `procfile`.  I suggest renaming `procfile` to `Procfile`.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I had Procfile in my local but on github, I still had procfile.